# Asp Net Core, Logic for custom request headers

Tags: asp.net-core

I'd like to create an Asp.Net Core MVC that can deny requests that lack specific headers.

For Example:

I want to access a Controller and and only allow Requests whose Header contains a specific (custom made) Authorization Type and Token.

I've done some research on it but I could not find anything on this topic that gave me an idea on how to even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could custom a middleware to check the request header type and value:

```
public class SimpleHeaderAuthorizationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SimpleHeaderAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Accept"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
        {
            if (authHeader == "specific_value")
            {
                //do your stuff....
                //throw new Exception("The HTTP header value is not correct!");
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            }
            await _next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            //reject the request if do not provide Authorization header
            //throw new Exception("Necessary HTTP header not present!");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
}
```

Create Middleware extension method:

```
public static class SimpleHeaderAuthorizationMiddlewareExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSimpleHeaderAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        return app.UseMiddleware<SimpleHeaderAuthorizationMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

The following code calls the middleware from `Startup.Configure`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{        
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseSimpleHeaderAuthorization();  //add this...

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed 